# Mobile First - Unable to Register Device for Push Notification

Tags: ios, cordova, amazon-web-services, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

It seems i am not able to register my iOS device on a remote server(MobileFirst Platform Server) that is being hosted for push notification.

Here is my code for registering the device

```
MFPPush.registerDevice(
  {},function(successResponse) {

  },
  function(failureResponse) {
    alert("Failed to register "+failureResponse);

});
```

I'm always getting a fail response which is

```
"Error Domain=com.ibm.mfp.push Code=5 \"Request failed: internal server error (500)\" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x156663e80> { URL: http://<server-ip:port>/imfpush/v1/apps/<app-bundleidentifier>/devices/FFF2867D-D43A-4FC0-A9C7-CBECF26BFFD6 } { status code: 500, headers {
  Connection = Close;
  \"Content-Length\" = 0;
  \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json\";
  Date = \"Mon, 20 Mar 2017 03:57:45 GMT\";
  \"X-Powered-By\" = \"Servlet/3.0\";
}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://<server-ip:port>/imfpush/v1/apps/<app-bundleidentifier>/devices/FFF2867D-D43A-4FC0-A9C7-CBECF26BFFD6, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}"
```

Other information:

1. My server ip is http://52.***.***:9080
2. I have set up "push.mobileclient" scope with custom security check, i have also set up "push.application.app-bundleidentifier" and "messages.write" at Confidential Clients
3. I have uploaded the apns-certificate-sandbox.p12 cert too for the app for MobileFirst server
4. The registration is successful when I'm registering against localhost.

I hope the data provided is sufficient.

thanks in advance

Comment: pls check ,server port are open for push notification and Error 500 is related to server side code.

Comment: HI @V12 , will check if the server ports in open for push notification. However for server side code... i don't think i wrote any server side code for device registration.

Comment: Hi @V12, i have check the server port and is open for push notification and is accessible via telnet. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Hii, may this link help you https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/
"
My guess is that this is due to registering against 10.0.1.6, which is an internal address.

1. Remove app from device
2. Register against an actual IP address such as 192..... or 168.... and try again.

You create tags either via the console or using REST API

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_tag_post.html  "

Comment: Hi @V12, i notice that the comment i having error code of "Error Domain=com.ibm.mfp.push Code=10", however the error I'm facing is "Error Domain=com.ibm.mfp.push Code=5"

Comment: @Chris, can you provide the exact build versions of your server and client.Also, what does the server log say? Any exceptions or errors?

Comment: Hi @VivinK, I'm using Mobile first 8.0 as server and iOS10 on iPad Pro as client, for the log, if you are mentioning on the "Error Log" tab on the left side bar. There isn't any error log.

Comment: @Chris, I meant server log. From the MobileFirst server

Comment: For me, app is getting register in mfp console. app also getting all tags that i created in mfp console. But while sending notification from console in iOS DEVICE,  I am not getting any notification. I am getting the same issue "Error Domain=com.ibm.mfp.push Code=5" for iOS app, I am not sure whats wrong going on.

Comment: Hi all, we manage to solve the issue. Below will be my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manage to solve this by updating the server and client mobile first platform version to the same one.